# Any shared R/W folder for any app and adb?

Tags: adb, file-management

I have a simple question about android but I just can't find any answer:

Is there any folder in a recent Android (10+) that is accessible in R/W to any application and also to `adb shell`, without root?

I've tried `/mnt/sdcard/` but files there belong to "root" when I list them via adb shell, and I cannot change their permission.
I just would like to be able to push a file via abd so that the application I'm developing can read and write this file.

Comment: Try `/data/local` and `/data/local/tmp`. They should be writable although some Android versions limit listing the files in these directories. But if you know the file-name reading and writing should work at least in one of them.

Comment: Thank you: /data/local/tmp works!